# HTML Text That Transitions from Bottom to Top

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am now trying to create an HTML div that transitions upward when text is added to its inner HTML. I do not know how to properly explain what I want, but I will try.

Say you were using a code editor with a live preview that updates constantly, and you had typed in something like this `<div></div>` and then you changed that code to `<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut.</div>`, and after you've changed that code the preview updated like this:
[image: text transitions up]

That is what I want text that transitions upward like the image above.

[Here](https://i.imgur.com/RpxTdZp.gif) is another example of text transitioning from bottom to top instead of the default appear out of nowhere.

Hope you've understood this, thanks in advance.

**Here is my code [live.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GaBKME)**

Answer (score 0):

TRY USING [div:empty{transition: (all) 970ms ease-in-out}] and see if it works

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I updated my post and now there is a link to my code live if it helps.

Comment: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/feb/22/using-css-transitions-to-slideup-and-slidedown found this post that will surely help you, the only downside is instead of an upward motion it'd go downward